# How to fix Linux Codename One build failed error

Tags: linux, build, codenameone

Submitting Android build fails in Linux Ubuntu 18.10 with JDK 11 on both IntelliJ v2019.1 and Netbeans v11.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':packageRelease'.

Caused by: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: 
Failed to read key from store "/tmp

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, 
making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
```

**The certificate verified OK as shown below using Keytool.**

`$ keytool -v -list -keystore Keychain.ks`

`Enter keystore password:`

`Keystore type: PKCS12`

`Keystore provider: SUN`

`Your keystore contains 1 entry`

`Alias name: mobitribe`
`Creation date: 14 Apr 2019`
`Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry`
`Certificate chain length: 1`
`Certificate[1]:`
`Owner: CN=MobiTribe, OU=ITDepartment, O=MobiTribe, L=Nairobi, ST=Kenya, C=KE`
`Issuer: CN=MobiTribe, OU=ITDepartment, O=MobiTribe, L=Nairobi, ST=Kenya,C=KE`
`Serial number: 5c0aaf6f`
`Valid from: Sun Apr 14 16:38:51 EAT 2019 until: Sat May 08 16:38:51 EAT 2060`

`Extensions:`
`#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false`
`SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: D2 77 22 2D 0A 63 22 52   DA C4 8B 4C CD B7 7E 1C  .w"-.c"R...L....
0010: B6 B3 14 DF`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your certificate key is invalid, you need to make sure your signing key was generated correctly and wasn't corrupted. I suggest verifying it with keytool.

Comment: I tested with keytool and alias and password are ok as shown in the edit above. **Could it be an issue with permissions on Linux that prevent the CN1 pluggin in the IDE from properly reading the keychain from the home directory?**

Comment: It's possible but unlikely. The server got something. I would suggest looking within codenameone_settings.properties and making sure it points to the right certificate file.